# RPM spec. How to avoid duplication

Tags: java, rpm

Hi i have a problem with code duplication while building rpm package.

I have a spec like this:

```
Summary     : ${product.id} ${rpmType}
Name        : ${product.id}_${rpmType}
.....


%build
%install


%files
%defattr(-,root,java,750)
%{home}

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}


%pre
CHECK_PAUSE=2;
echo -n "Stopping tomcat";
sh %{binary}/shutdown.sh
rc=0
while [ "$rc" == 0 ]; do
    sleep $CHECK_PAUSE;
    wget -q -O /dev/null -S http://localhost:8080/some-server/test;
    rc=$?;
done;
echo "Tomcat:  STOPPED"
mv %{home}/%{warname} %{home}/%{warname}.`date +%Y%d%m`
rm -rf %{home}/some-server
echo done.

%post
CHECK_PAUSE=2;
echo -n "Starting tomcat";
sh %{binary}/startup.sh
rc=1
while [ "$rc" -ne 0 ]; do
   sleep $CHECK_PAUSE
   wget -q -O /dev/null -S http://localhost:8080/some-server/test
   rc=$?
done
echo "Tomcat:  STARTED"

%preun
    if [ "$1" == "0" ]; then
    #STOP TOMCAT HERE SAME WAY AS IN PRE
fi


%postun
if [ "$1" == "0" ]; then
    #START TOMCAT HERE SAME WAY AS IN POST
fi
```

The scripts which are going to be executed in preun and postun sections are the same as in pre and post sections. But I don't want just copy/paste them. Is there some sophisticated solution to avoid code duplication here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

1. Create separate files for each piece of reusable shell script code.
2. Create a sort of pre-processor (possibly another shell script) that inserts the files created in Step 1 above into the spec file under the appropriate scriplet label (i.e. %pre, %post, %preun, %postun).

If you are using a source control management system, you might want to track these additional files as well.